# getting store view at admin gird

Tags: grid, store-view

How can I get the store_view into the admin grid?
I have a second table to store the key and the store_id.
how can I retrieve the data from that table to the grid?
I have below, but it is showing empty in the gird. how can I get the data from that table store_id  by using the key.

```
    /**
     * Check is single store mode
     */
    if (!$this->_storeManager->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $this->addColumn(
            'store_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Store View'),
                'index' => 'store_id',
                'type' => 'store',
                'store_all' => true,
                'store_view' => true,
                'sortable' => false,
                'filter_condition_callback' => [$this, '_filterStoreCondition']
            ]
        );
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use the renderer to get the value for column but if you use renderer i don't how to apply the filters on that column if you want to use the renderer let me know i will guide you and secound solution  is you can use the join in getCollection function.

Comment: can you guide me the first  option? I can give up filtering of this column. I need to create a new file for this column to render? someting like \Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Column\websiteid.php?

Comment: i have posted the answer try it and let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add renderer path in column like this way.

```
$this->addColumn(
            'store_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Store View'),
                'index' => 'store_id',
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'renderer' => 'Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Renderer\WebsiteId.php',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-type',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-type',
            ]
        );
```

And then create WebsiteId.php

> WebsiteId.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Renderer;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Vendor/Module/Model/Modelfactory;

class WebsiteId extends AbstractRenderer
{
     /**
      * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
     private $storeManager;
    protected $modelFactory; 
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,

        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->modelFacotry = modelFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function render(DataObject $row)
    {
       $slideId = $row->getSlideId();
       $model = $this->modelFactory->create();
       $storeIds = $model->getStores($slideId);
       //Here Stores id's are returned in the form of array.
       $storeName = [];
       foreach($storeIds as $items) {
          $storeName[] = $this->getStoreCodeById($items);
       }
       return implode(",", $storeName);
    }
     /**
      * Get Store code by id
      *
      * @param int $id
      *
      * @return string|null
      */
     public function getStoreCodeById(int $id): ?string
     {
        try {
            $storeData = $this->storeManager->getStore($id);
            $storeCode = (string)$storeData->getCode();
        } catch (LocalizedException $localizedException) {
            $storeCode = null;
            $this->logger->error($localizedException->getMessage());
        }
        return $storeCode;
     }
}
```

In your model class write this function

```
public function getStores($slideId){
 return $this->getResource()->getStores($slideId); 
}
```

In your resource model write this function

```
public function getStores($slideId){
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        $select = $connection->select()->from(
        $this->getTable('your_table_name'),
        ['store_id']
        )->where(
            'slide_id = ?',
            (int) $slideId
        );
        return $connection->fetchCol($select);
  }
```

It returns you the array of matching records store ids.

Comment: thanks for the input, however, I still a bit confuse the render part by retrieve data from the table base on the key. I created another post and ask about it. I wish you can help to take a look what I miss.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/350861/create-a-render-for-one-of-the-column-in-the-admin-grid

Comment: try the updated answer!

Comment: Thank you for the update, I am not too quite sure where the model class and the resource model location should be? can you give me an example of those 2 location please? thanks!

Comment: the model class is in Vendor/Module/Model/modelclass.php and rescource model in at Vendor/Module/Model/RescourceModel/modelclass.php

Comment: for creating models etc follow this https://www.codilar.com/blog/magento-2-models-resource-models-and-collections/

Comment: Thankyou very much! I finally get this running! I did modify a bit to fit my requirement. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad that it is working for you.